# Categories in static library for iPhone device 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, linker, static-libraries, categories

I have categories in my static library. Any application developer should set -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Flags" to use my static library properly. It works fine for iPhone device/iPhone Simulator 2.x and iPhone Simulator 3.0. But it crashes for iPhone device 3.0. As written [in this article](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/wiki/FAQ#My_app_works_in_the_iPhone_simulator,_but_crashes_on_the_device) it is new linker bug. They suggest to use one more linker flag: -all_load. But when I add this flag, build fails too, because there are duplicate symbols.

How to use categories in static libraries for iPhone device 3.0? Any suggestions?

Comment: I have same problem, did you resolve it ?

Comment: In the latest linker it appears that this has been fixed and -all_load is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 10):

We [ran into the same problem](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f2bb1e2503b9c861?hl=en#) (under 3.0, -ObjC no longer links in categories) within the [Core Plot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  All I can say is that for us, we were able to add the -all_load option to the Other Linker Flags within the target application and that did away with the runtime errors.  We didn't see any warnings for duplicate symbols.

I've filed a bug report for the linker behavior, as I'm sure others have.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug caused by trying to fix another bug with a hack.
The -all_load fix for the category bug is a total hack.

See [here](http://blog.binaryfinery.com/universal-static-library-problem-in-iphone-sd) for more.

Answer (score 0):

When you add -all_load to your other linker flags, make sure, all frameworks, the library uses are linked with your target app. Otherwise, it will fail to compile. In my case, I had a Category for MKMapView and did not bind the MapKit Framework with my target app, thus the class which the category belongs to wasn't found at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same "duplicate symbols" problem. Without the `-all_load` flag, we had to also include all libraries our library linked against in the app link line. Removing these from the app link line solved the issue.