# NSConcreteData vs NSData

Tags: iphone

I have added an extension to NSData (base64 extension), which I kept over a separate infrastructure class lib project. But when i use this method from my main project i am getting an error like this: "-[NSConcreteData encodeBase64]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x121e60'".

But if i keep the same class in my main project itself, this will execute with out any issue.

I call this method in the following way: 
[dev setToken:[token encodeBase64]];

Please suggest why this is not working if i put the extension in another project. (I am already using some other extensions, eg. for NSDate,  like this with out any issue.)

Answer (score 3):

Is this on iPhone OS 3.0?  The 3.0 SDK [broke the use of -ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147676/categories-in-static-library-for-iphone-device-3-0), but you usually are able to link in categories for a static library by adding the -all_load option to Other Linker Flags within your target application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the metadata necessary to configure a category is usually stripped by the linker because it appears to be dead. If you add the "-ObjC" LDFLAG to your project it will tell the linker to link all the potential ObjC info even if it appears to be dead.

Comment: In the flags for the app, or the library?

Comment: i have added on both app and lib.