# iPhone: Using static library in an application crashes the device but not the iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a library I made, and now I want to utilize it in an application. I've believe I've properly linked to the library. Here are all the things I've done:

- Set the header search path
- Set other linker flags to "-ObjC"
- Added the static library xcode project
- Made sure the lib.a was listed as a framework target
- Added the library as a direct dependency

Like I said in the title, I've successfully run the app with the static library in the simulator. Once I try testing the app using the device, it crashes the second it has to use a function from the library:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSDate firstOfCurrentMonth]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3841bb44'
2009-10-10 12:45:31.159 Basement[2372:207] Stack:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the current SDK linker. See [this post](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/wiki/FAQ#My_app_works_in_the_iPhone_simulator,_but_crashes_on_the_device) for more information on the problem and possible workarounds. (also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147676/categories-in-static-library-for-iphone-device-3-0).)

**Update:**

Another thing you can try is to remove the static library and include the library's source files directly in the application's project. I was facing a similar static library linking issue and that's what I ended up falling back on to get it to run successfully. If that works (however gross a workaround it may be) then it's definitely a linker issue.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to help... I added that to the application and then the library.

Comment: As stated in the second link, you may need to add the "-all_load" option to the Other Linker Flags in your build settings to get categories from your static library to be linked in properly.  This is a known issue with the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently. I was unable to get the -all_load to work, when I noticed that another category I had DID work. I was lazy for this category and included it in with another file.

I eventually created a dummy class (no methods, instance variables) and included the implementation of my categories in the .m file for that dummy class. After doing this my categories started working even after I removed the -all_load flag.

This was on iPhone OS 3.1.3.

This certainly is not the RIGHT way to fix it, but it seemed to work.

Full sample code is on my [blog](http://iphonedevelopmentexperiences.blogspot.com/2010/03/categories-in-static-library.html) for my (trivial) categories.