# Accessing private variable from Category generates linker error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, linker-errors

I have the following code:

```
@interface UIAcceleration (Simulation)

- (id) initWithTimestamp:(NSTimeInterval)aTimeStamp
                     X:(UIAccelerationValue)ax
                     Y:(UIAccelerationValue)ay
                     Z:(UIAccelerationValue)az;

@end

@implementation UIAcceleration (Simulation)

-(id)initWithTimestamp:(NSTimeInterval)aTimeStamp
                     X:(UIAccelerationValue)ax
                     Y:(UIAccelerationValue)ay
                     Z:(UIAccelerationValue)az 
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        timestamp = aTimeStamp;
        x = ax;
        y = ay;
        z = az;
    }

    return self;
}       

@end
```

when compiling this for simulator SDK everything works fine. When compiling for device SDK I get the following linker error:

```
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.x", referenced from:
      _OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.x$non_lazy_ptr in UIAcceleration+IRowAdditions.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.y", referenced from:
      _OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.y$non_lazy_ptr in UIAcceleration+IRowAdditions.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.z", referenced from:
      _OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.z$non_lazy_ptr in UIAcceleration+IRowAdditions.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.timestamp", referenced from:
      _OBJC_IVAR_$_UIAcceleration.timestamp$non_lazy_ptr in AccelerometerSimulation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong? What is different between linking against Simulator frameworks (namely UIKit) and linking against device frameworks?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and re-building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as none of the answers given helped, I did something diferent.

I created a class with exactly the same interface as UIAcceleration. Because both of them have the same memory layout, I can safely cast between pointers of UIAcceleration and my class. At least as long as gcc wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably included only the simulator version of the UIKit framework. I'm not so sure about this, but go to the left pane in Xcode and under the **Frameworks** folder, right click on **UIKit.framework** and **Get Info**. On mine, the path is `/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework` and right under that it says **Path Type:** "Relative to Current SDK". That should automatically pull the correct framework depending on what you're building for.

Worth a check.

Comment: I have checked that. Everything was set excactly the way you said. Not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147676/categories-in-static-library-for-iphone-device-3-0) with categories on the iPhone.  Try adding -ObjC (iPhone OS 2.x) and -all_load (iPhone OS 3.0) to your "Other Linker Flags".

Comment: Didn't help either. Thanks for your suggestion.