# IPhone: Adding Category to CoreLocation threw link error. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, linker

I added a category to CLLocation in CoreLocation but kept getting a link error.
I search around and through process of TRY IT AND BE DAMNED I fixed the problem by adding 
-framework CoreLocation to Other Linker Flags
But dont know why?
I'm guessing its something to do with CoreLocation being and external framework.

The Code:
**CLLocation+DistanceComparison.h**

```
#import < Foundation/Foundation.h >
#import < CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h >

static CLLocation * referenceLocation;
@interface CLLocation (DistanceComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult) compareToLocation:(CLLocation *)other;
@end
```

**CLLocation+DistanceComparison.m**

```
#import "CLLocation+DistanceComparison.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@implementation CLLocation (DistanceComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult) compareToLocation:(CLLocation *)other {
    CLLocationDistance thisDistance = [self getDistanceFrom:referenceLocation];
    CLLocationDistance thatDistance = [other getDistanceFrom:referenceLocation];
    if (thisDistance < thatDistance) { return NSOrderedAscending; }
    if (thisDistance > thatDistance) { return NSOrderedDescending; }
     return NSOrderedSame;
    }
@end
```

**Build Error:**

```
 Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SortedLocations.app/SortedLocations normal i386  
 cd /Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/034.SortedLocations/SortedLocations  
 setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5  
 setenv PATH   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"  
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk -L/Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/034.SortedLocations/SortedLocations/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/034.SortedLocations/SortedLocations/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/034.SortedLocations/SortedLocations/build/SortedLocations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SortedLocations.build/Objects-normal/i386/SortedLocations.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/clearbrian/Documents/Development/IPhoneDevelopment/034.SortedLocations/SortedLocations/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SortedLocations.app/SortedLocations  

 Undefined symbols:  
 ".objc_class_name_CLLocation", referenced from:  
 literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocation in RootViewController.o  
 ld: symbol(s) not found  
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Getting link error when we added category
 maybe because its external framework

got help from
 hg clone https://traillocation.googlecode.com/hg/ traillocation
 They added Foundation in Other Linker Flags for one of their targets
 so I tried adding CoreLocation see attempt 2

ATTEMPT 1 : didnt work - see attempt 2

NOTE: to use this category on the 3.0 device, the -all_load linker flag
 must be set in users of this library due to a toolkit bug.
 See [Categories in static library for iPhone device 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147676/)

Right Click on project name in Groups and Files pane
 Get Info
 Build tab
 type Other Linker Flags in search
 when found
 Double click in right column
 add -all_load

ATTEMPT 2 -
 Right Click on project name in Groups and Files pane
 Get Info
 Build tab
 type Other Linker Flags in search
 when found
 Double click in right column
 add -framework CoreLocation
 close
 if you reopen the params are on two lines, this is ok
 -framework
 CoreLocation
 Clean all targets
 Build
 seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't include the CoreLocation framework in your "Link binary with libraries" phase of your target.  To do so, double click your target, go to the first tab, hit the + button in the bottom left, find the CoreLocation framework in the list, and hit "Add".